# Why did Cloud City have the huge chutes leading into open air?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

Towards the end of "The Empire Strikes Back", Luke escapes from Darth Vader by jumping down a chute... which opens up into open air, and leaves him dangling on a mast...

Why does Cloud City have these death traps in the first place?

Comment: Garbage dumps, probably.

Comment: Same reason Death Stars have open exaust ports leading to reactors; and Emperor's throne room had a bottomless pit. George Lucas School of Engineering and Design.

Comment: Darth Vader force-choked anyone who tried to start OSHA.  Even his evil had limits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the film's [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(junior_novelization)), the **big tube** is an **exhaust pipe**. Luke thinks that the the *smaller sub-tubes* are **likely there to carry loose waste away from the reactor core:**

> Luke sailed into the exhaust pipe, a metal-lined tubular tunnel that
> twisted down and away from the reactor shaft. The pipe’s walls were
> smooth, sending Luke on an uncontrolled slide until he entered what
> seemed to be a dip in the pipe, and slowed to a stop. But before he
> could plan his next move, a trap-door dropped open beneath him,
> plunging him down another pipe.
>
> Luke’s mind raced, trying to figure out where the second pipe would
> carry him. As the pipe twisted into an almost vertical slope, **he
> guessed the pipes were designed to expel stray matter from the reactor
> shaft.** He extended his limbs in an attempt to slow his descent, but
> the effort was too much for his drained, battered body. He continued
> to slide.

The [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(novel)) backs this up, describing them as a **large exhaust pipe** and a **smaller exhaust pipe** (but without going into further detail):

> The Dark Lord watched until he saw the youth’s body sucked into a
> large exhaust pipe in the side of the reactor shaft. When Luke
> vanished, Vader quickly turned and hurried off the platform.
>
> Luke sped through the exhaust shaft trying to grab the sides to slow
> his fall. But the smooth, shiny sides of the pipe had no hand-holes or
> ridges for Luke to grasp.
>
> ...
>
> Luke could no longer slow his inexorable slide out the exhaust pipe.
> He slid the final few centimeters and then dropped through the cloudy
> atmosphere, his body spinning and his arms flailing to grip on to
> something solid.

---

This is further backed up by this official storyboard slide, clearly labelled as **INT. [e.g. Interior shot] -EXHAUST PIPE**

[image]

---

It also marries up nicely with the [film script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html):

> **INTERIOR: REACTOR SHAFT**
>
> *Suddenly Luke is sucked into an exhaust pipe in the side of the shaft. When Vader sees this, he turns and hurries off the platform.*

Comment: Luke has a heck of a constitution. He was just severely physically and emotionally shocked to the point that he was willing to let himself fall into a seemingly bottomless pit rather than let Darth Vader help him, and yet he still has the presence of mind to wonder about the purpose of the pipe he ended up in.

Comment: @Xantec - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qAKXK_aLeA

Comment: "a trap-door dropped open beneath him". Because what's an exhaust tube without a trap door?

Comment: @JonKiparsky - You build access hatches so that you can get in to remove any debris (or dead workers) that have plugged up the tubes.

Comment: He had regenerated his hand!  Jedi healing is awesome.